# How much do answers A,B,C link with the answer on question D?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis

I have 9 questions in 3 different blocks where you answer with a number (1-7). And there is a question (how did you like this place overall?) that is answered (1-10). I need a way to find out how much each block (and maybe also each question) affects the tenth question. Preferably using excel or R. The number of respondents are in the thousands if that makes any difference.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "9 questions in 3 different blocks" but the default choices for categorical response data are multinomial logistic or ordinal logistic. More information would be helpful.

Comment: Question 1-3 is regarding one area (customer support), Question 4-6 regarding availability, 7-9 regarding the quality of the help. I guess the use of the word block might have been a bad choice.

Answer (score -1):

The problem of addressing effect of all 9 questions on 10th can be easily addressed by any multiclass classification technique (logistic regression/SVM). One way of converting block data into scalar would be performing PCA on the block and selecting major principle component. In R, this could be done as:

fit <- principal(block_i, nfactors=1, rotate="varimax")

for each block. This could then be followed by standard classifier.

Comment: I guess the use of the word block was a bad one since it's not blocking in the usual sense perhaps. Question 1-3 is regarding one area (customer support), Question 4-6 regarding availability, 7-9 regarding the quality of the help. I have the data in a matrix 10x10000, I guess using logistic regression in R on the matrix might be a straight forward sollution?

Comment: The response variable is on a 1-10 scale, so logistic regression wouldn't fit.  There's something to the PCA idea, but it would need to be exploratory factor analysis:  PCA works for objectively measured data, and here we have opinions.

Comment: Whatever statistical associations one might find connecting Answers A, B,+ C to D, it's by no means a foregone conclusion that the former are *causing* the latter.  That's why I changed the wording in the title.  If you want to demonstrate causation to the discerning reader you've got more work in front of you.